# Linux file content replacement issue

Tags: linux, sed, perl, awk

I am using Linux Red Hat 5 Enterprise version.

For all files in the current directory, I want to replace all occurrences of `/foo/goo/zoo` （which are contained in file contents) to `/a/b/c`.

Any ideas how I can implement that quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed -i 's!/foo/goo/zoo!/a/b/c!g' *
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find DIR -type -f -exec sed -i 's!/foo/goo/zoo!/a/b/c!g' '{}' ';'
```

(the solution of ignacio is correct, but the glob operator `*` might run out of space when facing lots of files).